# TypeError: scope.viewDate.clone is not a function

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I'm trying to build a date time picker using angular and momentjs.
I've built my directive to populate the days but 'm getting the error "TypeError: scope.viewDate.clone is not a function" I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong and how I can fix it.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('datepicker', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

            scope.viewDate = moment;
            var selectedDate = null;

            function generateDays() {
                scope.days = [];

                var startOfSelectedDate = moment.isMoment(selectedDate) ? selectedDate.clone().startOf('day') : null;
                var startDate = scope.viewDate.clone().startOf('month').startOf('week').startOf('day');
                var endDate = scope.viewDate.endOf('month').endOf('week').endOf('day');

                while (startDate < endDate){
                    scope.days.push({
                        label: startDate.date(),
                        inMonth: startDate.month() === scope.viewDate.month() && startDate.year() === scope.viewDate.year(),
                        date: startDate.valueOf(),
                        selected: startDate.isSame(selectedDate)
                    });
                    startDate.add(1, 'day');
                }
            }
            generateDays();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed to execute the moment while defining viewDate. your code will be

```
scope.viewDate = moment();
```